# Mootools convert Hash to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, mootools

I have Hash obj:

```
var obj = {a,b,c,...};
obj = $H(obj);
```

I need to convert it to simple array

```
[a,b,c,..]
```

How can I do?
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.getValues(myObject)` to get an Array of all values.

`Object.getKeys(myObject)` to get an Array of keys.

For 1.2 simply, `Hash` provides the same methods.

And **don't** use `Objects {}` to store lists like in your example. `Arrays` are for lists, `Objects` are for *associative arrays*.

**EDIT**:
Since version 1.3 `Object.getValues` and `Object.getKeys` has been deprecated and replaced by `Object.keys` resp `Object.values`.

Answer (score 2):

since you use $H I am assuming older ver of mootools, 1.2.x since it got deprecated in 1.3 in favour of the new Object. construct

The hash had a .each method:

```
var Hobj = $H({
    tool: "bar",
    ghost: "goblin"
});

var arr = [];

Hobj.each(function(value, key) {
    arr.push(value); // what to do with key?
});

console.log(arr);
```

an alternative that grabs the complete objects with their keys but not as array keys:

```
Hobj.each(function(value, key) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    arr.push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the values in the array:

```
var arr = [];
for(var prop in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        arr.push(obj[prop]);
    }
}
```

If you want the property names to be in the array:

```
var arr = [];
for(var prop in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        arr.push(prop);
    }
}
```

the hasOwnProperty call is important because it will filter out inherited functions and private members of the mooTools hash class that you don't probably want in your resulting array

Comment: hash is not really a normal object - its a modified Object type that allows for prototyping (frown). and it also has pre-defined methods, one of which is `.each` - that would be the clean API'd mootools way to iterate through it.